# Difference of ''as if '' , '' like '' , ''as ''

Tags: conjunctions

> 1) He acts **like** he doesn't care about anything.
>
> 2)He acts **as if** he doesn't care about anything.
>
> 3)He acts **as** he doesn't care about anything.

What is the difference between three sentences in meaning . I think first and second sentences mean the same . But third one is different from them . I think it means that he acts in the way he doesn't care about antything ( it doesn't make sense in my oppinion). But what I couldn’t understan is whether like used like both “ as “ and “ as if “ in general.  Can you explain difference ?

Comment: The third example should ideally have a comma before "as":  "He acts, as he doesn't care about anything." That's a rather artificial sentence, however, since "acts" generally doesn't occur in isolation. More likely would be something like "He acts silly, as he doesn't care about anything." Even then, I would suggest using "since" instead of "as": "He acts silly, since he doesn't care about anything."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first example is typical informal spoken English. Though it is colloquial, I should hesitate to use it in a written or formal context; others might disagree.

As you surmise, the second example means exactly the same thing - that **he acts in a manner indicating that....** - but is more formally stated. An alternative to **He acts as if...** is **He acts as though....**. The meaning is the same.

In your third example, **as** would be interpreted to mean **because**. That's to say that he acts (in whatever manner was being referred to) because he doesn't care about anything.

So the third example means something completely different from the first two.